# Django mysql tuple index out of range

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-mysql

My views.py looks like following:

```
@api_view(('GET',))
def save_progress_for_particular_user(request, exerciseId, rating):

    #view to call stored proc that stores the progress for a particular user
    #save_progress(user_id,exercise_id,rating,date)   

    result=Exercise_progress_model.save_progress_for_particular_user(
        request.user.id, exerciseId, rating, datetime.date.today())

    serializer = ExerciseProgressSerializer(result, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

My `models.py` looks like following:

```
class Exercise_progress_model(models.Model):
    # Model that will be rendered on the UI
    #Field for storing intensity level
    INTENSITY_LEVEL_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'Really simple'),
        (2, 'Rather Simple'),
        (3, 'Simple'),
        (4, 'Okay'),
        (5, 'Difficult'),
        (6, 'Rather Difficult'),
        (7, 'Really Difficult'),
    )

    intensity_level = models.IntegerField(choices=INTENSITY_LEVEL_CHOICES)

    #Field for storing progress
    progress = models.IntegerField(default='0')

    #Field for storing exercise type

    EXERCISE_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'Best stretch'),
        (2, 'Butterfly reverse'),
        (3, 'Squat row'),
        (4, 'Plank'),
        (5, 'Push up'),
        (6, 'Side plank'),
        (7, 'Squat'),
    )
    exercise_id = models.IntegerField(choices=EXERCISE_TYPE_CHOICES)

    #Field for storing current date
    current_date = models.DateField()

    #Field for storing user rating
    user_rating = models.IntegerField(default='0')

    # static method to save progress for a particular user  
    @staticmethod  
    def save_progress_for_particular_user(user_id, exercise_id, rating, date):

        # create a cursor  
        cur = connection.cursor()  
        # execute the stored procedure passing in   
        # search_string as a parameter  
        cur.callproc('save_exercise_state', [user_id, exercise_id, rating, date,])  


        # grab the results   
        result = cur.fetchall()
        cur.close()

        User_progress_list = [] 
        for row in result:
            Epm = Exercise_progress_model()

            Epm.intensity_level=row[0]
            Epm.progress=row[1]
            Epm.exercise_id=row[2]
            Epm.user_rating=row[3]
            Epm.current_date=row[4]

            User_progress_list.append(Epm)

        return User_progress_list
```

My `serializers.py` looks like following:

```
class ExerciseProgressSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
     intensity_level = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
     progress = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
     exercise_type = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)     
     user_rating = serializers.IntegerField(required=True) 
     current_date = serializers.DateField()
```

My stored procedure looks like following:

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE save_exercise_state(  
 p_user_id int, p_exercise_id int, p_rating int, p_date date   
)   
BEGIN  
DECLARE lv_current_intensity, lv_progress, lv_final_intensity int;
DECLARE lv_date date;

select intensity_level into lv_current_intensity

from demo_exercise_state where 
user_id=p_user_id and exercise_id=p_exercise_id;

select progress into lv_progress
from demo_exercise_state where 
user_id=p_user_id and exercise_id=p_exercise_id;

select current_date into lv_date
from demo_exercise_state where 
user_id=p_user_id and exercise_id=p_exercise_id;

select lv_progress, lv_current_intensity, lv_date;

If lv_date=p_date then 
    select "OK";
end if;

if p_rating=0 then
    set lv_progress=lv_progress;
elseif p_rating=1 then
    if lv_progress=3 then 
        set lv_progress=0;
        if lv_current_intensity = 7 then 
            set lv_final_intensity = 7; 
        else 
            set lv_final_intensity = lv_current_intensity + 1;
        end if;
    else 
        if lv_current_intensity=7 then
            set lv_progress=0;
            set lv_final_intensity=lv_current_intensity;
        else    
            set lv_progress=lv_progress+1;
            set lv_final_intensity=lv_current_intensity;
        end if;
    end if;

elseif p_rating =-1 then

    if lv_progress=0 then 

        if lv_current_intensity = 1 then 
            set lv_final_intensity = 1; 
            set lv_progress=0;
        else 
            set lv_final_intensity = lv_current_intensity - 1;
            set lv_progress=3;
        end if;
    else 
        set lv_progress=lv_progress-1;
        set lv_final_intensity=lv_current_intensity;    
    end if;

end if;

        Update demo_exercise_state
        SET progress = lv_progress,
        intensity_level = lv_final_intensity,
        `current_date` = p_date,
        user_rating = p_rating
        WHERE user_id = p_user_id AND exercise_id = p_exercise_id;

        SELECT intensity_level, progress, exercise_id, user_rating , current_date
        FROM demo_exercise_state 
        WHERE user_id = p_user_id AND exercise_id = p_exercise_id AND user_rating=p_rating;  

END
//
```

Screenshot of the result of executing this proc for 
***call save_exercise_state(4,1,1,curdate());*** is as following

[image]

When I call this view I get tuple index out of range error for the line  `Epm.user_rating=row[3]`.

What is the reason for this? Is there any workaround?

Comment: index out of range error means your `row` contains only 3 elements instead of expected 5 elements, which means your call doesn't return all values. Debug (or make a `print` statement) of the `row` variable and see what it contains.

Comment: Yes I tried that and fetchall() basically doesn't give me all the above columns, I wonder what could be the reason?

Comment: The problem resides in your stored procedure. I'm not that good in mysql, but I would recommend you add the pure `mysql` tag to this question to find someone who could help